# Moto 360 doesn't have a step detector?

Tags: android, android-sensors, wear-os

So I'd like to be able to record the events by the Step Detector on the Moto 360, but when I run this code on the wear module:

```
mStep = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
if (mStep == null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Step is null");
}
```

It prints out the "Step is null" message in logcat.  Using TYPE_STEP_COUNTER does result in an object getting returned and I'm able to listen to events from it, but I'm looking for the latency found in TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR objects.

Does the 360 just not have this sensor?  That seems pretty inexplicable since the Counter exists.  Similar code works just fine on my Nexus 5.

Comment: yes the moto 360 has a pedometer https://play.google.com/store/devices/details?id=motorola_moto_360_leather_black

Comment: Right, but there's two different ways to measure steps in code.  One of them isn't working, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: What _PackageManager.hasSystemFeature(String)_ tells you? Is feature step detector available?

Comment: It's not difficult to count steps using an accelerometer, and Moto doesn't have to abstract a step detector to do so...

Comment: @harism It returns false.  That's pretty odd, since the step counter is there.  AFAIK they're part of the same API level so it's pretty perplexing that it's not available.

Comment: @Zwei01 for a reason unknown to me, step counter and detector are separate features. So obviously they are not part of the same API but there is, or might be, some difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem before, and the step counter is the easiest one to use for most applications. The step detector will only deliver an event when a step actually occurs, so unless the step is occurring in the few milliseconds the device is awake between suspend cycles, it will get no data. It should be registering for TYPE_STEP_COUNTER to get a reliable count.

Answer (score 0):

do you add this feature in your manifest?
uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"
add this and try again, i am sure that moto 360 has stepcounter sensor, because i have used it to do many things